# How to reload all kinds of functions and all HTML code in JavaScript to restart a game?

Tags: javascript, function, reload

Clicking on the Home button at the end of this project brings it to the beginning, but no function is reset. Level buttons are not also being enabled anew. If I enable those level buttons by writing some extra code for enabling, then the number of buttons given for each level will be doubled after selecting the level. In other words, for the first time due to selecting the basic level, there were 4 options, But when I click on the last home button and then select the medium level to play the game from the beginning, it becomes 16 options instead of 8.

```js
//VARIABLE DECLARATION PART

let frontpage = document.querySelector(".front-page");
let playbutton = document.querySelector(".play");
let levelpage = document.querySelector(".levelpg");
let startbtn = document.querySelector(".startbtn");
let maingame = document.querySelector(".maingame");
let easybtn = document.querySelector(".easy");
let mediumbtn = document.querySelector(".medium");
let hardbtn = document.querySelector(".hard");
let nextbtn = document.querySelector(".nextbtn");
let pagecount = document.querySelector('.gamepagecount');
let getnumberdiv = document.querySelector('.numberbtn').children;
let resultpg = document.querySelector('.resultpage');
let backhome = document.querySelector('.backhome');
let finalscore = document.querySelector('.score');
let resulttext = resultpg.children[1];
let changeimg = document.querySelector('.resultpage img');


// PLAYBUTTON CLICK

playbutton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  frontpage.classList.add("hidden");
  levelpage.classList.remove("hidden");
  levelpage.classList.add("visibility");
});

//GAME START FUNCTION

function startGame(level) {
  if (level == "easy") {
    mediumbtn.disabled = true;
    hardbtn.disabled = true;
    easybtn.disabled = true;
    easybtn.classList.add('levelcolor');

    startbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      pagecount.innerHTML = `1 of 10`;
      nextbtn.disabled = true

      levelChange(4);
      gameInterfaceChange()
      mainGame(10);

      //NEXTBUTTON FUNCTION 

      nextbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

        enableBtn(4)
        pageCount(10);
        mainGame(10);
      })

    });
  }
  else if (level == "medium") {
    mediumbtn.disabled = true;
    hardbtn.disabled = true;
    easybtn.disabled = true;
    mediumbtn.classList.add('levelcolor');


    startbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      pagecount.innerHTML = `1 of 15`;
      nextbtn.disabled = true

      levelChange(8);
      gameInterfaceChange();
      maingame.style.top = "20%";
      mainGame(20);

      //NEXTBUTTON FUNCTION 

      nextbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

        enableBtn(8)
        pageCount(15)
        mainGame(20);

      })
    });
  }
  else if (level == "hard") {
    mediumbtn.disabled = true;
    hardbtn.disabled = true;
    easybtn.disabled = true;
    hardbtn.classList.add('levelcolor');


    startbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      pagecount.innerHTML = `1 of 20`;
      nextbtn.disabled = true

      levelChange(12);
      gameInterfaceChange();
      maingame.style.top = "12%";
      mainGame(30);

      //NEXTBUTTON FUNCTION 

      nextbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

        enableBtn(12)
        pageCount(20)
        mainGame(30);

      })
    });
  }
}

//PAGE SLIDING FUNCTION

function gameInterfaceChange() {
  levelpage.classList.remove("hidden");
  levelpage.classList.add("hidden");
  maingame.classList.remove("hidden");
  maingame.style.top = "25%";
  maingame.classList.add("visibility");
}


// FUNCTION OF RANDOM INPUTING NUMBER IN DIV 

function mainGame(maxnum) {

  let numboxlen = getnumberdiv.length;
  let wrongnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxnum) + 1;
  let getnumber = [];

  //DUPLICATE RANDOM NUMBER CHECKING

  for (let i = 0; i < numboxlen; i++) {
    let check = getnumber.includes(wrongnum);

    if (check === false) {
      getnumber.push(wrongnum);

    }
    else {
      while (check === true) {
        wrongnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxnum) + 1;
        check = getnumber.includes(wrongnum);
        if (check === false) {
          getnumber.push(wrongnum);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // NUMBER PUTTING IN InnerHtml

  for (var j = 0; j < numboxlen; j++) {
    if (getnumber[j] < 10) {
      getnumberdiv[j].innerHTML = '0' + getnumber[j];

    }
    else {
      getnumberdiv[j].innerHTML = getnumber[j];
    }
  }

}

// BUTTON ADDING ACCORDING TO THE LEVEL 

function levelChange(divnum) {
  for (let index = 0; index < divnum; index++) {
    let newBtn = document.createElement('button');
    let newbtnNode = document.createTextNode('');
    newBtn.appendChild(newbtnNode);
    let gamebtn = document.getElementById('numbrbtn');
    gamebtn.appendChild(newBtn);
    newBtn.setAttribute("onclick", `numberClick(${index},${divnum})`);

  }
}

//RIGHT - WRONG CHECKING FUNTION 

var right = 0;
var wrong = 0;


function numberClick(index, divnum) {

  let rightnumberindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * divnum);

  if (index == rightnumberindex) {

    nextbtn.disabled = false
    right++;

    //RIGHT AND WRONG BACKGROUND ADDING AND BUTTON DISABLE

    getnumberdiv[index].classList.add("rightans");

    for (let i = 0; i < divnum; i++) {
      getnumberdiv[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
  else {

    nextbtn.disabled = false
    wrong++;

    //RIGHT AND WRONG BACKGROUND ADDING AND BUTTON DISABLE

    getnumberdiv[rightnumberindex].classList.add("rightans");
    getnumberdiv[index].classList.add("wrongans");

    for (let i = 0; i < divnum; i++) {
      getnumberdiv[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
}

// BUTTON ENABLE ON NEXT BUTTION CLICK

function enableBtn(divnum) {

  for (let i = 0; i < divnum; i++) {

    nextbtn.disabled = true
    getnumberdiv[i].disabled = false;
    getnumberdiv[i].classList.remove("wrongans");
    getnumberdiv[i].classList.remove("rightans");

  }
}


//PAGE COUNTING ACCORDING TO THE LEVEL

let currentpg = 1;

function pageCount(levelPg) {

  currentpg++;

  if (currentpg <= levelPg) {
    if (currentpg == levelPg) {
      nextbtn.innerHTML = 'Result'
      pagecount.innerHTML = `${currentpg} of ${levelPg}`;
    }
    else {
      pagecount.innerHTML = `${currentpg} of ${levelPg}`;
    }
  }
  else {
    result();
  }

}

//FINAL RESULT FUNTION

function result() {

  maingame.classList.remove("visibility");
  maingame.classList.add("hidden");
  resultpg.classList.remove('hidden')
  resultpg.classList.add('visibility')

  if (right > wrong) {
    changeimg.setAttribute('src', 'trophy.png')
    resulttext.innerHTML = `You Win`;
    finalscore.innerHTML = `Your Right Score  is : ${right} out of ${right + wrong}`;
  }

  else if (right == wrong) {
    changeimg.setAttribute('src', 'draw.png')
    resulttext.innerHTML = `It's Draw`;
    finalscore.innerHTML = `Your Right Score  is : ${right} out of ${right + wrong}`;
  }

  else if (right < wrong) {
    changeimg.setAttribute('src', 'lose.png')
    resulttext.innerHTML = `You Lose`;
    finalscore.innerHTML = `Your Right Score  is : ${right} out of ${right + wrong}`;
  }
}


//BACK TO THE HOME FUNCTION

backhome.addEventListener('click', () => {
  frontpage.classList.add("visibility");
  frontpage.classList.remove("hidden");
  resultpg.classList.add('hidden')
  resultpg.classList.remove('visibility')

// enable level button
  mediumbtn.disabled = false;
    hardbtn.disabled = false;
    easybtn.disabled = false;
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.guessing-game {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #bd3f32, #cb356b);
}

.guessing-game .front-page .front-img {
  height: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}

.guessing-game .front-page img {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.guessing-game .front-page .front-text h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.guessing-game .front-page .front-text p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.guessing-game .front-page .front-text button, 
.resultpage button ,
.levelpg .easy,
.levelpg .medium,
.levelpg .hard,
.maingame .nextbtn {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  background-color: #d64d5d;
  box-shadow: rgba(17, 17, 26, 0.1) 0px 1px 0px,
    rgba(17, 17, 26, 0.144) 0px 8px 24px, rgba(17, 17, 26, 0.1) 0px 16px 48px;
}

.guessing-game .front-page .front-text button:hover,
.maingame .nextbtn:hover,
.resultpage button:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: #c22f40;
}


/* Level page */

.visiblepg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12%;
  width: 290px;
}

.levelpg h1 {
  margin: 45px 0 40px 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.levelpg .easy,
.levelpg .medium,
.levelpg .hard {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 12px;
  background: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #c22f40;

}

.startbtn {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.levelpg i {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.levelpg i:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: #c22f40;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

/* GAME PART */

.maingame .gamepagecount {
  background-color: #d64d5d;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.maingame .gametext {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.maingame .numberbtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.maingame .numberbtn button {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-content: space-around;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 0 21%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #c22f40;
  font-weight: 600;

}

.maingame .numberbtn button:nth-child(1),
.maingame .numberbtn button:nth-child(5),
.maingame .numberbtn button:nth-child(9) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.resultpage h1 {
  margin: 0px 0 40px 0;
}
.resultpage img {
  margin-top: 45px;
  width: 50%;
}

/* PRE DEFINE  CSS */
.visibility {
  visibility: visiible;
  opacity: 2s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-30px);
}
.levelcolor {
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: white !important;
  background-color: #c22f40 !important;
}

.rightans {
  background-color: #27ae60 !important;
  color: white !important;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.wrongans {
  background-color: #fd4631 !important;
  color: white !important;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>Guessing Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="guessing-game">
        <div class="front-page">
            <div class="front-img">
                <img src="./question.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="front-text">
                <h1>Guessing Game</h1>
                <p>
                    You just need to chose the right number from the option. If your
                    guess is right more than wrong , you will win otherwise you will
                    fail!  Let's see how good your sixth sense is!!!
                </p>
                <button class="play">Let's play</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="levelpg hidden visiblepg">
            <h1>Game level</h1>
            <button class="easy" onclick="startGame('easy')">Easy</button>
            <button class="medium" onclick="startGame('medium')">Medium</button>
            <button class="hard" onclick="startGame('hard')">Hard</button>
            <button class="startbtn"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="maingame visiblepg hidden">
            <p class="gamepagecount">1</p>
            <p class="gametext">Guess the number you think is right</p>
            <div class="numberbtn" id="numbrbtn"></div>
            <button class="nextbtn">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="resultpage levelpg hidden visiblepg">
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <h1></h1>
            <div class="score"></div>
            <button class="backhome">Home</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In short, as soon as I click on the home button, I want the game to start anew, all the functions will be reset anew, and the HTML will be reset anew also. I hope my problem is enough clear to understand.

Comment: Hey 2 out of 20, I must be psychic!

Comment: Hey, Did you give my project 2 out of 20?  If yes, then why?  Let me know!

Comment: There isn't any rating 0 to 20 only an upvote (I gave you both votes BTW) and a downvote. I played your game and got 2 out of 20 tries, I was being facitious saying,*"I must be psychic!"*

Comment: Hahahaha!I see.I thought you gave a rating for my project. My mistake.Thanks for the comment. And also so playing my game....

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

I just  add a reload function to solve this problem.

```
backhome.addEventListener('click', () => {
  frontpage.classList.add("visibility");
  frontpage.classList.remove("hidden");
  resultpg.classList.add('hidden')
  resultpg.classList.remove('visibility')
  //reload function
  window.location.reload();

})
```